# Ruby 2.0 on windows connecting to MS SQL varchar(max) truncating to 2048

Tags: ruby, sql-server, freetds, varcharmax

background:
i have written a few ruby transformation scripts
they get data from MS SQL transform them and then store it back to the data base 
i am using tiny tds gem which works over freetds

--Problem:
for columns in sql that are varchar max and have string length greater than 2048 when data is extracted using tiny tds these columns get truncated to 2048 length exactly.

Freetds protocol 7.2 does fix this issue but is not available on windows platform
the code works perfectly on a mac. but due to integration with ETL tool i have to deploy it on a windows machine.

-- does any one have a solution for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have any code doing this myself, but have you tried using the [set textsize command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186238.aspx). I think the default is 2048.

From the MS article on Set TextSize

```
The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver and SQL Server 
Native Client OLE DB Provider for SQL Server automatically 
set TEXTSIZE to 2147483647 when connecting.
```

But I think you may need to call this explicitly (using the same connection, prior to getting data).

Comment: thats it ... it worked .. thanx alot ... just before ur select SET TEXTSIZE number .. n it words jst fine

Comment: Great. I did not know if it would work, glad to know it does. The default 2048 limit is pretty stupid these days as MS clearly knows since they change it to 2GB automatically on their stuff. Considering that you were getting 2048 bytes, I am pretty sure it is still the default.